# How to get a code signing certificate without address on ID?

Tags: windows, code-signing

Last year I got a quite cheap code singing certificate from ascertia.com but they do not sell (cheap) ones any more.
So I looked for another one and found various Sectigo/Comodo resellers at about 80 CHF.

But **I am unable to get my identity verified, because my (Swiss) ID card and passport do not have my address on them**. And they require either this or I have to pay a notary to prove my address (which is obviously quite expensive).

How can I (as a Swiss) get a cheap code signing certificate which is approved by Microsoft Authenticode?

Comment: I’m currently having the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes I found one, I've added it below. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found another code signing certification authority: [ssl.com](https://www.ssl.com/certificates/code-signing/buy/)

They accepted my "prove of residence" when I was entered at [Google my Business](https://www.google.com/business), which I was able to do for free.

One disadvantage is, it costs $129.00 for 1 year. Another one, they were quite slow to issue the certificate.

When I would have to do it again, I would try:

1. Create myself (First + Lastname) at my address in [Google my Business](https://www.google.com/business)
2. Buy a code signing certificate and create a certification request at [ssl.com](https://www.ssl.com/certificates/code-signing/buy/)
3. Wait 2 days and see if they approve the request or otherwise I would contact the support via their live chat. (They are quite helpful. However, I guess they are based in America or at least I met them only during the business times there.)
4. Optional: After I get the certificate, I would remove the entry again in [Google my Business](https://www.google.com/business).